# Print console.error log on screen in div

Tags: html, angularjs, error-handling

I'm using angularJs for my project. Our customer would like to print all the console.error's in a div on the webpage itself.

Can't find a useful example on the net...

Thanks for the help!

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

As documentation said:

> Any uncaught exception in angular expressions is delegated to $exceptionHandler

```
angular.
  module('exceptionOverwrite', []).
  factory('$exceptionHandler', ['$log', 'logErrorsToBackend', function($log, logErrorsToBackend) {
    return function myExceptionHandler(exception, cause) {
      logErrorsToBackend(exception, cause);
      $log.warn(exception, cause);
    };
  }]);
```

Here you can read [more](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler)

So all you have to do is create this service (as at the example) and add logic to insert your errors to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

For a *very* simple solution, and if you know the functions you want to watch, just set the error to $scope directly, e.g. $scope.errorMsg = error.